Calculating of point stationing along axis in QGIS
I have this issue in QGIS: I need to calculate the stationing of start- and endpoints from line features (cable management system) alongside an axis (railway). The stationing should run along the axis and correspond to the foot of the perpendicular from the points next to the axis. The length of the axis is up to 150 km, so scale corrections are necessary accordingly.
I tried to do a Python script using Chat GPT but the results were not accurate, 60 m away from the real distance. I couldn't find any systematic errors, otherwise I would have used another scale factor.
Here ist the code from Chat GPT. You can ignore the formatting of the results.
    import qgis.core
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProject,
    QgsGeometry,
    QgsPointXY,
    QgsFeature,
    QgsField,
    QgsDistanceArea,
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
    QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QMessageBox
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.utils import iface
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# Funktion zur Auswahl eines Layers aus einer Liste der verfügbaren Layer
def select_layer(prompt):
    layer_names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    selected_layer, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(None, "Layer auswählen", prompt, layer_names, 0, False)
    if ok:
        return QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selected_layer)[0]
    else:
        return None

# Funktion zur Abfrage der Strecke und Rückgabe des zu addierenden Wertes
def select_strecke():
    items = ["2811", "2550"]
    strecke, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(None, "Strecke auswählen", "Wählen Sie die Strecke aus:", items, 0, False)
    if ok and strecke:
        if strecke == "2811":
            return 139961
        elif strecke == "2550":
            return 103900
    return None

# Auswahl der Layer
linie_layer = select_layer("Wählen Sie den Linienlayer aus:")
if not linie_layer:
    QMessageBox.critical(None, "Abbruch", "Kein Linienlayer ausgewählt. Skript wird abgebrochen.")
    exit()

punkt_layer = select_layer("Wählen Sie den Punktlayer aus:")
if not punkt_layer:
    QMessageBox.critical(None, "Abbruch", "Kein Punktlayer ausgewählt. Skript wird abgebrochen.")
    exit()

# Abfrage der Strecke
zu_addierender_wert = select_strecke()
if zu_addierender_wert is None:
    QMessageBox.critical(None, "Abbruch", "Keine gültige Strecke ausgewählt. Skript wird abgebrochen.")
    exit()

# Geometrie- und Distanzwerkzeuge initialisieren
distance_area = QgsDistanceArea()
distance_area.setSourceCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:25832'), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
distance_area.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

# Temporären Layer erstellen und Punkt-Layer kopieren
temp_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:25832", "Aufgelotete_Punkte", "memory")
temp_provider = temp_layer.dataProvider()

# Attribute zum temporären Layer hinzufügen
temp_provider.addAttributes(punkt_layer.fields().toList())
temp_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Stationierung', QVariant.Double), QgsField('Stationierung_Text', QVariant.String)])
temp_layer.updateFields()

# Funktionen zum Berechnen der Stationierung entlang der Linie
def get_distance_along_line(line_geom, point_geom):
    nearest_point_context = line_geom.closestSegmentWithContext(point_geom.asPoint())
    nearest_point = QgsPointXY(nearest_point_context[1])
    
    # Berechnung der Distanz entlang der Linie
    total_distance = 0.0
    previous_point = None
    for vertex in line_geom.vertices():
        if previous_point is not None:
            segment_length = distance_area.measureLine(QgsPointXY(previous_point), QgsPointXY(vertex))
            total_distance += segment_length
            if distance_area.measureLine(QgsPointXY(previous_point), nearest_point) < segment_length:
                segment_length = distance_area.measureLine(QgsPointXY(previous_point), nearest_point)
                total_distance += segment_length
                break
        previous_point = vertex
    
    return total_distance, nearest_point

# Formatieren der Stationierung
def format_stationierung(distance):
    km = int(distance // 1000)
    m = int(distance % 1000)
    return f"S-P2-1_{km}+{m:03d}"

# Punkte und Attribute vom Punkt-Layer kopieren
features = punkt_layer.getFeatures()
for punkt_feature in features:
    new_feature = QgsFeature()
    new_feature.setGeometry(punkt_feature.geometry())
    new_feature.setAttributes(punkt_feature.attributes())
    temp_provider.addFeature(new_feature)

# Temporären Layer editierbar machen
temp_layer.startEditing()

# Durch alle Punkte im temporären Layer iterieren, auf die Linie aufloten und Stationierung berechnen
for punkt_feature in temp_layer.getFeatures():
    punkt_geom = punkt_feature.geometry()
    nearest_distance = float('inf')
    stationierung = None
    projected_point = None

    for linie_feature in linie_layer.getFeatures():
        linie_geom = linie_feature.geometry()
        distance, nearest_point = get_distance_along_line(linie_geom, punkt_geom)
        
        if distance < nearest_distance:
            nearest_distance = distance
            stationierung = distance
            projected_point = nearest_point

    if projected_point is not None:
        # Stationierung um den ausgewählten Wert erhöhen
        adjusted_stationierung = stationierung + zu_addierender_wert
        
        # Stationierung und projizierten Punkt dem Punktattribut hinzufügen
        punkt_feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(projected_point))
        punkt_feature.setAttribute('Stationierung', adjusted_stationierung)
        punkt_feature.setAttribute('Stationierung_Text', format_stationierung(adjusted_stationierung))
        temp_layer.updateFeature(punkt_feature)

# Änderungen speichern und Layer aktualisieren
temp_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)

iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info", "Punkte erfolgreich aufgelotet und Stationierung in temporärem Layer hinzugefügt.", level=Qgis.Info)

And here is an image, I hope this suffice.


Can you please show an image of what you want to achieve? If you put the [tag:pyqgis], I highly recommend inserting your trial code, otherwise the thread might be closed.
